# Select between active images in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am currently stuck trying to get Gatsby to switch the main image on a product page with a click. I see a lot of solutions that use state and switching the active class with state manipulation but for some reason I am unable to add state or any other function into my current js file. I am using Gatsby and Gatsby Images to render the images.

What I have it like now [I want to be able to select between these three images and make the selected image the big main one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUHGD.png)

Here is the code I have, I know its messy but have been fidgeting it around to try to get it to work

```
const Product = ({ data }) => {
    const post = data.shopifyProduct;


    return (
        <Layout>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <h5>Price: <span>{post.variants[0].price}</span></h5>
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.description }}
            />
            <GatsbyImage id="main" image={getImage(post.images[0])} alt={post.images.altText} />
              <div class="gallery">
                <GatsbyImage id="img-2" image={getImage(post.images[0])} alt={post.images.altText} />
                <GatsbyImage id="img-2" image={getImage(post.images[1])} alt={post.images.altText} />
                <GatsbyImage id="img-2" image={getImage(post.images[2])} alt={post.images.altText} />
              </div>
        </Layout>
    );
  };


Product.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Thanks for checking it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the React `useState` hook (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html):

```js
// If you haven't already:
// import * as React from 'react'

const Product = ({ data }) => {
    const post = data.shopifyProduct;
    const [imgIndex, setImgIndex] = React.useState(0 /* or your default */)

    return (
        <Layout>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <h5>Price: <span>{post.variants[0].price}</span></h5>
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.description }}
            />
            <GatsbyImage id="main" image={getImage(post.images[imgIndex])} alt={post.images.altText} />
              <div class="gallery">
                <GatsbyImage onClick={() => { setImgIndex(0) }} id="img-2" image={getImage(post.images[0])} alt={post.images.altText} />
                <GatsbyImage  onClick={() => { setImgIndex(1) }} id="img-2" image={getImage(post.images[1])} alt={post.images.altText} />
                <GatsbyImage  onclick={() => { setImgIndex(2) }} id="img-2" image={getImage(post.images[2])} alt={post.images.altText} />
              </div>
        </Layout>
    );
  };


Product.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: If this helped you, could you [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?